# How can I get information of a tag with the Stack Exchange API?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki, api, tag-wiki-excerpt

The [API documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags-by-name#order=desc&sort=popular&tags=java&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) of usage of `/tags/{tags}/info GET` does not give us this information:

[image]

[image]

How can I get this text description?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need [another API method](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wikis-by-tags) to get this information. The excerpt (shown in your screenshot) is included by default, but there's also [tag information in the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) which isn't included. If you want that too, you have to set a [filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters); [this call](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wikis-by-tags#tags=java&filter=!nNPvSNMavg&site=stackoverflow&run=true) does that:

[image]

Comment: Is `!nNPvSNMavg` some kind of ID for a pre-determined filter? Or can we determine it logically somehow? The linked page about filters didn't clearly explain this for me.

Comment: There's an `[edit]` link next to the filter which lets you (un)select certain fields. After you click the Save button in the dialog, the documentation site will let you know the filter ID.

Comment: So the intended workflow is that you create the filter you want through the GUI, it gets saved on the server, and then you refer to it by ID in future API queries?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel No, you can re-create the same filter by changing the fields yourself, manually. The filter determines which information you get from the API. Think of it like a bunch of flags, saying what you want.

Comment: how can we specify two tags, like java, sql in this api?

Comment: @DenysMedvediev that's described [on another documentation page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/vectors)